# Isn't derivative of holomorphic function continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

On page 65 of Shakarchi's Complex analysis , problem 5 asks that if f is continuously complex differentiable on some set , under suitable conditions show that Goursat's theorem holds. He also advices to use Green's theorem to use here.

I think I know the idea, which is to write $f = u + iv$ and then represent the integral over the boundary of triangles as integration of curl over interior but I don't get why he mentions that $f'$ is continuous, because if it is holomorphic derivative is also holomorphic and continuous by default.

Comment: Yes, holomorphic functions are locally analytic. But when building up the theory, one usually uses Goursats's theorem to prove Cauchy's integral formula. And this is what gives you the result that the derivative of a holomorphic function is holomorphic

Comment: What is exactly your question? It depends on what you have already proven about holomorphic functions...

Comment: To wrap it up, he assumes weaker condition so that assuming continuous derivative we can prove Goursat => CIT => derivative is continous showing we could just start with this assumption to develop theory

Comment: Exactly, what i was confused was why he dismisses information that he has already proven in the text but he was just trying to show that we could start with weak (but equivalent) conditions